# How to get output of two different commands in two columns on powershell?

Tags: powershell, output

Suppose I have two commands: 
1) Get-Date
2) netstat -aon | findstr 20484 | Measure-Object -line

How to run these two commands in a loop, with a sleep time of 60 seconds? The output file should have the results of these two commands printed in two different columns like this:

```
Date and Time         Netstat
2/2/2020 00:10          15
2/2/2020 00:11          20
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following:

```
while (1) {
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        'Date and Time' = Get-Date -Format 'M/d/yyyy HH:mm'
        'NetStat' = netstat -aon | findstr 20484 |
                    Measure-Object -Line | Select -Expand Lines
    }
    sleep 60
}
```

**Explanation:**

`1` in a `while` condition always returns true so the loop will never end unless manually broken.

`Measure-Object -Line` returns a `TextMeasureInfo` object. Since you only want the number of lines from that output, you need to retrieve the value of the `Lines` property. Piping to `Select -Expand Lines` does this.

The `-Format` parameter of [Get-Date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-6) allows for a string format representation to be entered provided the desired format is allowed.

`[PsCustomObject]` is a type accelerator for a custom object. This allows the ability to create the headers/properties you want while providing their associated values. The values and/or properties can be added at the time of declaration or later.

The `@{}` syntax surrounds a hash table. The purpose of a hash table is to hold key/value pairs. This makes for an easy way to create a quick object since PowerShell v3.

`sleep` is an alias for [Start-Sleep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/start-sleep?view=powershell-6). It can accept `-Seconds` or `-Milliseconds` with `-Seconds` being the default parameter bind when only a value is provided.

---

If you don't want the loop to go on indefinitely, you can add a counter like so to loop 5 times:

```
$count = 5
while ($count--) {
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        'Date and Time' = Get-Date -Format 'M/d/yyyy HH:mm'
        'NetStat' = netstat -aon | findstr 20484 |
                    Measure-Object -Line | Select -Expand Lines
    }
    sleep 60
}
```

---

I don't know if you are searching for a port number or process identifier. Since either one could theoretically be in your output, you may want to consider that case. If you are looking for a port, I would use `findstr :20484` instead. If you only want a process identifier, I would use `netstat -ano | Where {$_ -match '\s20484'}`

Comment: Note that it will take 60 seconds for the first two objects to appear.

Comment: @js2010, True. We could just pipe the custom object to `Out-Host`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(netstat -aon | findstr 20484 | Measure-Object -line | Select-Object @{l="Date";e={(Get-Date)}}, * | Format-Table | Out-String).Trim()

while( $true ) {

    sleep -Seconds 60

    (netstat -aon | findstr 20484 | Measure-Object -line | Select-Object @{l="Date";e={(Get-Date)}}, *  | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | Out-String).Trim()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use a more PowerShelly way instead of `findstr`:

```
$maxLoops = 5   # set a max to the loop
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $maxLoops; $i++) {
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        'Date and Time' = Get-Date
        'Netstat'       = (netstat -aon | Select-String 20484).Count
    }
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
}
```

Comment: Note that implicit format-table will wait for 2 objects before outputting anything.